# Reasignar valores aleatoriamente a una variable, con una distribución de probabilidad

Tags: python, python-2.7

Supongamos que hemos declarado una serie de variables (V1, V2, V3, V4) y otra serie de variables (probabilidades):

```
V1="A"
V2="B"
V3="C"
V4="D"
Prob_V1=0.2  #probabilidad de reasignar "A" a V1
Prob_V2=0.1  #probabilidad de reasignar "B" a V1
Prob_V3=0.4  #probabilidad de reasignar "C" a V1
Prob_V4=0.3  #probabilidad de reasignar "D" a V1
```

Pregunta concreta:
¿Cómo podríamos reasignar (de manera randomizada) el valor de la variable V1 teniendo en cuenta las diferentes probabilidades?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te he entendido bien lo que quieres es obtener una opción aleatoria de entre un conjunto (como hace `random.choize()`) pero que cada opción tenga una probabilidad distinta de ser elegida. Hay varias formas de hacer esto:

- Si puedes/quieres usar la librería externa [`NumPy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/1.11.3) lo tienes muy sencillo ya que existe un método para hacer presisamente esto, [`numpy.random.choice()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice). Para ello solo tienes que instalar Numpy si no lo tienes instalado y pasarle a la función un iterable con las opciones y otro con las probabilidades usando el parametro `p`:

  ```
  import numpy

  opciones = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
  probabilidades = [0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3]

  eleccion = numpy.random.choice(opciones, p=probabilidades)
  print(eleccion)
  ```

  Ten en cuenta que tus probabilidades deben sumar 1 para que el método funcione.
- Otra posibilidad es crear tu propia función calculando las probabilidades acumuladas en una lista ordenada, eligiendo un `float` entre 0 y la suma de todas las probabilidades y usar [`bisect.bisect()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect) para retornar el indice correspondiente. En el siguiente ejemplo se se elige el número que nos sirve de base aleatoria usando [`random.random()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html):

  ```
  from random import random
  from bisect import bisect

  opciones = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
  probabilidades = [0.9, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1]

  def choice(opciones, probs):
      probAcumuladas=[]
      aux = 0
      for p in probs:
          aux += p
          probAcumuladas.append(aux)
      r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
      op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
      return opciones[op]

  eleccion = choice(opciones, probabilidades)
  print(eleccion)
  ```

  La idea de este código nace del último ejemplo que da la propia documentación de Python [aquí](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#examples-and-recipes).

**Edición:**

Para calcular la suma acumulada podemos usar [`itertools.acumulate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) si usamos Python 3.2 o superior:

```
from random import random
from bisect import bisect
from itertools import accumulate

opciones = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
probabilidades = [0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3]

def pChoice(opciones, probs):
    probAcumuladas = list(accumulate(probs))
    r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
    op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
    return opciones[op]

eleccion = pChoice(opciones, probabilidades)
print(eleccion)
```